# Get xml mapping from Excel with python

Tags: python, excel, xml, parsing

I have a excel file, in this file i have a table with 3 columns, and 3 rows. Every column has a name and there is XML mapping for every column. Why.

Just to convert this Excel into xml file for example.

The table has columns has a name ' first name' and there is a row with value 'abdou' and xml tag for first name is going to be '<f_name>'

My problem is I want to know from the Excel the name of tag of every column with instruction python

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I didnt find any instruction to get' xml mappping' with any columns

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimum reproducable example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example